# Не загружается библиотека pyautogui

Tags: library, pyautogui

Попытался установить библиотеку pyautogui, но при попытке запустить программу вылетает ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Павел\Desktop\TestProject\SchoolProject\Main.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyautogui ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'`
```

Пользуюсь PyCharm, Python 3.9. Взял даже готовый проект, основанный на этой библиотеке, так же не работает, как починить?

Comment: «Попытался установить библиотеку pyautogui» — как именно попытались?

Comment: Вы уверены что запустили проект в той же среде, что и установленный модуль. Хотя вынужден признать, что у меня тоже возникали проблемы с тем, что питон в нужном окружении не видит установленной библиотеки.